# Controlling Name Resolution server (DNS) address per request

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, dns

Looking for ideas on how to generate a Name Resolution request and specify to which server to dispatch the request.

I'm working on Linux.

Up until now, I found two options:

1. Use an external library which can be hooked for achieving this. 
   Anyone knows a **reliable** [DNS library](http://c-ares.haxx.se/otherlibs.html) that can be used for a production system?
2. Use Network Namespaces to virtualize the stack and use mounting to link the name resolution server files per namespace (see iproute2 latest version). Requests issued from each namespace may have different servers.

please share your thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

Linux actually comes with a resolver API.  See the man(3) page for 'resolver', and link your application with `-lresolv`.

The libsres library (dnsval) from the [DNSSEC-Tools](http://www.dnssec-tools.org/) project definitely lets you send queries to a particular server.  I know because I've done just that inside the [DNSSEC-Check](https://www.dnssec-tools.org/wiki/index.php/DNSSEC-Check) application, which is also part of the DNSSEC-Tools project.

Comment: I think getaddrinfo() will give a better cover here. The main problem still stands, there is no option to control the DNS Server used for each query (or query groups), they both use a DNS from a system level pool (file).

Comment: ok, I added another reference that I know will do what you want.